# $(...).sortable is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, sortablejs

I have imported the sortable and jquery references to my html, however, it says that

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

and

> Uncaught Error: jQuery is required for jquery-sortablejs

I have never used jquery before hence new to this all. I have taken this exact code as a demo of this website, and it is working on code pen, however wont work on my own laptop.

```js
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable-list',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var changedList = this.id;
    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    var positions = order.join(';');

    console.log({
      id: changedList,
      positions: positions
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<html> 
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/rankWebsite/js/main.js"></script>




<body> 

<h1> Rank Images</h1>

<ul id="image-list1" class="sortable-list">
    <li id="a">A</li>
    <li id="b">B</li>
    <li id="c">C</li>
  </ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look at the errors in the console. You're including `jquery-sortable.js` ***before*** `jquery.js`. You're also including multiple versions of jQuery. Remove 1.12.4 and move 3.5.1 to that position.

Comment: what do you mean by jquery.sortable.js before jquery.js? i only want to use jquery for the srotable functions

Comment: I've added an answer to show you what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code is due to the order of the script references. Any script which relies on jquery.js *has* to be included in the page after jQuery. In addition you're including two versions of jQuery which can cause issues. I'd suggest keeping 3.5.1 and removing 1.12.4. Try this:

```js
$('.sortable-list').sortable({
  connectWith: '.sortable-list',
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var changedList = this.id;
    var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
    var positions = order.join(';');

    console.log({
      id: changedList,
      positions: positions
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sortablejs@latest/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-sortablejs@latest/jquery-sortable.js"></script>

<h1> Rank Images</h1>
<ul id="image-list1" class="sortable-list">
  <li id="a">A</li>
  <li id="b">B</li>
  <li id="c">C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much! the errors are now all gone from the console, however the elements are not moving as they have on this page: https://codepen.io/Sinetheta/pen/qvbCr